# Extracting only modified codes by using git diff

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want the diffrence between two separate branches B1 and B2 to extract the modified codes in B2.
Here, the B1 is more like a parent/Developer branch under which other feature branches(e.g B2,B3,B4,B5) are created, modifications are done and then merged into B1.
The issue i am facing is, whenever i do a `git diff --name-status` between the B1 and B2, or between commit id's of the same, i get more than what is modified in B2.

The reason is, before B2, other branches(B3,B4) may have been merged into B1 which results in B2 getting behind B1 due to the changes made by the other branches merged into it.

Now, if i do a `diff`, it not only gives me code names changed in B2, but also B3 and B4.

Is there any way to implement this. I have tried all possible ways that i am aware of.

Comment: Note that when you compare the merge base commit with the tip commit of branch B2, you're seeing what's different in the snapshot at the tip of the branch, vs what's in the common commit shared by branches B1 and B2.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
git diff --name-status B1...B2 # triple dot
git diff B1...B2
```

That should work